# Console contents

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get the contents of console window. I got the following code but it is not working,,..
can anyone tell me how to get the console contents(Characters)?????

```
    DWORD nLength=2;
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow("ConsoleWindowClass",NULL);
    LPTSTR lpCharacter=" ";
    COORD dwReadCoord;
    dwReadCoord.X=11;
    dwReadCoord.Y=11;
    LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsRead=0;
    bool a= ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(hWnd,lpCharacter,nLength,dwReadCoord,lpNumberOfCharsRead);
```

Comment: Is it your own console window (i.e. does your program run in this console)? If yes, it's easy to fix; if no, I'm not so sure. `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter` doesn't work with HWNDs, it works with "console (pseudo-)file handles".

Comment: Then `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) will give you the right `HANDLE` to use (you might have to reopen `"CONOUT$"` with `GENERIC_READ` access, but in the absense of I/O redirection there is no need to do that).

Comment: I used this but this didnt work HANDLE hand=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

Comment: Nevertheless it *is* the right way, so debug it. Handle an error (let us know what `GetLastError` says after failure). Print a numeric value of handle (should be an odd integer, not too big). And btw, you can't read characters into a string literal `" "`, you should use an array.

Comment: In the best case, this is _horribly_ system dependent (yes, I still remember programs that assumed a specific memory layout and bypassed BIOS to run faster under DOS; they broke, often crashing the system, when that changed).

Comment: @vonbrand yes it is. It's okay to use system-dependent knowledge during debugging, though (I could have to ask about target system details if `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter` were slightly *more* portable).

Comment: "Do funny stuff just while getting it to run, we'll clean up later" is a sure recipe to disaster...

Comment: Note that the consoles got the ability to remember line wrappings (and undo them) in Windows 10. I haven't tried to access that programmatically. But it would be nice to retrieve long lines as such, not wrapped

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it. `GetNumCharsInConsoleBuffer` is to get the number of characters in the console buffer. Creates a dynamically allocated array with that value. And finally `ReadConsoleBuffer` will fill your buffer with the contents of the console buffer.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD GetNumCharsInConsoleBuffer()
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO buffer_info;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &buffer_info);
    return (DWORD)((buffer_info.dwSize.X * ( buffer_info.dwCursorPosition.Y + 1)) - (buffer_info.dwSize.X - (buffer_info.dwCursorPosition.X  + 1)));
}

DWORD ReadConsoleBuffer(char* buffer, DWORD bufsize)
{
    DWORD num_character_read = 0;
    COORD first_char_to_read = {0};  
    ReadConsoleOutputCharacterA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), buffer, bufsize, first_char_to_read, &num_character_read);
    buffer[bufsize-1] = '\0';

    return num_character_read;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Writting\nin\nthe\nbuffer\n");

    DWORD bufsize = GetNumCharsInConsoleBuffer();   
    char* buffer = new char[bufsize];
    memset(buffer, 0, bufsize);

    ReadConsoleBuffer(buffer, bufsize);    
    puts("\nBuffer contents:");
    puts(buffer);

    delete[] buffer;
    system("pause"); 
    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Writting
in
the
buffer
Buffer contents:
Writting
in
the
buffer

Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```